# multiple autocomplete dropdowns not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

When I have one autocomplete dropdown for one field everything works fine, however when I add more dropdowns for more fields the value of the input fields is no longer populated with the text of the li which is returned from the php file which is called

The following works where .sugnorm1 is the class of the li

```
var delay = (function () {
var timer = 0;
return function (callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#quality1').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    delay(function () {
        $.post("functions/autocomplete.php", {
            quality:$(this).val(),
            questionname:"<?php echo $_SESSION['question']; ?>",
            count:1
        }, function (response) {
            $('#qualitySuggest1').hide();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('qualitySuggest1', '" + escape(response) + "')", 20);
        });
        return false;
    }, 20);
});
});

$('.sugnorm1').live("mouseover mouseout click", function(event) {
    if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
        $(this).addClass('sughover');
    } else if ( event.type == "click") {
        $("#quality1").val($(this).text());
        $("#qualitySuggest1").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('sughover');
    }
});

$("#quality1").blur(function () {
    $("#qualitySuggest1").hide();
});


});
function finishAjax(id, response) {
$('#' + id).html(unescape(response));
$('#' + id).show();
} //finishAjax
```

However if I add another field the quality suggest .hide() is called but I can't get anything else such as an alert to work in the event.type == click for both of the fields.

```
var delay = (function () {
var timer = 0;
return function (callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
};
})();
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#quality1').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    delay(function () {
        $.post("functions/autocomplete.php", {
            quality:$(this).val(),
            questionname:"<?php echo $_SESSION['question']; ?>",
            count:1
        }, function (response) {
            $('#qualitySuggest1').hide();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('qualitySuggest1', '" + escape(response) + "')", 20);
        });
        return false;
    }, 20);
});
$('#quality2').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    delay(function () {
        $.post("functions/autocomplete.php", {
            quality:$(this).val(),
            questionname:"<?php echo $_SESSION['question']; ?>",
            count:2
        }, function (response) {
            $('#qualitySuggest2').hide();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('qualitySuggest2', '" + escape(response) + "')", 20);
        });
        return false;
    }, 20);
});
});

$('.sugnorm1').live("mouseover mouseout click", function(event) {
    if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
        $(this).addClass('sughover');
    } else if ( event.type == "click") {
        $("#quality1").val($(this).text());
        $("#qualitySuggest1").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('sughover');
    }
});

$("#quality1").blur(function () {
    $("#qualitySuggest1").hide();
});

$('.sugnorm2').live("mouseover mouseout click", function(event) {
    if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
        $(this).addClass('sughover');
    } else if ( event.type == "click") {
        $("#quality2").val($(this).text());
        $("#qualitySuggest2").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('sughover');
    }
});
$("#quality2").blur(function () {
    $("#qualitySuggest2").hide();
});


});
function finishAjax(id, response) {
$('#' + id).html(unescape(response));
$('#' + id).show();
} //finishAjax
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: jsfiddle wouldnt hurt ;)

Comment: Im new to jsfiddle and I don't know how it works. I added the code but I was unable to get the jquery to run successfully. Maybe the extra code would help womeone help me solve my problem? http://jsfiddle.net/uberbrainchild/UvfqD/3/

Comment: Seems like my blur function was being called instead of the click function when clicking an <li>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My click event was being called after the blur event, thus the suggestion dropdown was hidden. I solved this by changing my click event to mousedown. Mousedown will then be called before blur.